# unable to install karma on windows vista for angular-phonecat tutorial

Tags: windows, angularjs, node.js, karma-runner

I am trying to run through the angular-phonecat tutorial. npm install failed for me, so I installed the packaged individually, except for karma which fails for me. Can someone help me solve this issue. ws compilation seems to be a known issue for windows, and the solution given for it is to update npm or reinstall nodeJs, i have done both of that, and I still get the error below. Please help.

`$ npm install -g karma`

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1

ws@0.4.32 install C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_
modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm ERR! ws@0.4.32 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.32 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6002
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma"
npm ERR! cwd c:\JavaScript\angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```